# JS "Type Error: '3' is not a function" (evaluating 'newArray.length()')

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to increment the last element of a vector in JS, but it throws me an Error type, saying `newArray.length()` is not a function. This is the code:

```
var sampleArray = [0,0,7];

var incrementLastArrayElement = function(_array) {
    var newArray = [];

    newArray = _array;

    var length = newArray.length() - 1;

    newArray[length] += 1;

    return newArray;
};

console.log(incrementLastArrayElement(sampleArray));
```

Hope you could explain to me what is happening.

Thank you

Comment: remove the parenthesis, length isn't a function

Comment: that's lack of basics and probably typing `javascript array length` in google would be way quicker than create question

Comment: Thank you all. But maybe I don't deserve that much negative score...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length) is a **property** and not a function.

> The length **property** represents an unsigned, 32-bit integer that specifies the number of elements in an array.

**Code**

```
var length = newArray.length - 1; // Remove `()`
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't have parenthesis

```
var length = newArray.length - 1;
```